# Why "Jack Ryan"...when it isn't?

Tags: character, book-adaptation, jack-ryan-tv

The body of work from Tom Clancy regarding Jack Ryan runs so contrary to the material in the new Prime series "[**Tom Clancy's Jack Ryan**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5057054/?ref_=nv_sr_1)" that other than the name and very few other factors "this" Jack Ryan is NOT "that" Jack Ryan.

They are both CIA analysts and they interact with a guy named James Greer. But other than that this (new) character might as well be Joe Turner (Robert Redford in Three Days of the Condor), yet they produce and publicize this new series around a link to the original Clancy character.

Why? (as in, where is the advantage or motive? what benefit is gained?) I've only seen a few episodes, and I would not call it bad (nor am I willing to call it 'great') but Jack Ryan, Joe Turner, Bob Smith are just names and these episodes cannot be (canon) prequels to the original character, so why bother trying to foist the illusion? Or am I missing a stronger connection to the Tom Clancy character here that justifies the usage of this brand a little more?

Would this be a lesser show if they just called it "Bob Smith"

Comment: To be perfectly honest, this looks more like a "I don't think the new Jack Ryan series should be considered canon, who's with me?" rant than an actual good faith question.

Comment: Dissapointed.. you aren't the only one mate, but this doesn't sound like a question but you looking for some other people to agree with you.

Comment: As it's written, this question is likely to get deleted. You sorta answer your own question in the title ("it isn't"). But it's a reasonable question (I answered it), so perhaps you just need to rephrase it. Perhaps something like "Other than Jim Greer, how is the new Jack Ryan similar to previous Jack Ryans?"

Comment: I tried to improve the question a little more into not looking like a rant and asking more of a real question. Seeing how we successfully did questions of this kind before and it has a good answer adressing its concerns, this seems like a sufficiently reasonable question now.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Thanks for the edits to the question. I chose to roll back that most recent as it really gets to the heart of what I am asking (I truly wasn't meant to be a 'rant' about the show) It comes down to why use 'an established' character when you could just as easily create a whole new one? Would the new show be compromised by calling it "Bob Smith"?

Comment: To what end? You already made that point. Where's the point of having some invented example name there. I googled "Bob Smith" and it seems you just made it up to drive home your point. A point that has been elaborated on end in the preceding paragraphs. *Obviously* "Bob Smith" as a *title* (rather than just a character name) isn't going to work and *you know that*. So why even ask such a highly rhetorical and contentious question at the end? Phrases like that are what makes such things *look* like rants to others and I'm trying to reduce that, since I *do* think this is a valuable question.

Comment: It appears that I didn't do a very good job of making the point, as several others appeared to have missed it. Yes, I choose "Bob Smith" as a very generic name that has no other previous (that I know of) canon. Certainly a 'clever' name might give a show more curb appeal, but that was NOT the point of the question, but rather about tying the show to a previously establish character then completely (or nearly completely) abandoning almost everything that is 'known' about that character.

Comment: And people *are* answering how it isn't entirely throwing away everything we know about Jack Ryan, which seems to adress your question, too. Of course new answers could as well extend this with more explanations along the obvious "it sells, duh!" line of thought for why they chose Jack Ryan over something self-made, but I don't feel the existing answers miss the point here.

Comment: The problem is that the question is twofold. You state the premise that the series isn't Jack Ryan enough and *based on that* ask why someone would butcher an existing property *when* it doesn't have anything to do with it. For that to be answered we'd either have to accept the premise you just put there and go after the question *you* think to be asking. Or we can take a look at your premise and see if we can maybe make the secondary question moot by correcting that.

Comment: As of the point where I posed this question I was (and still am) barely more than a full episode into the series. It might well be true that they do a more thorough job of tying the two together (I have no issue with changing the timeline for instance) If the premise is faulty, then so be it. I appreciate, but don't necessarily accept, the one and only answer so far that suggests this may be the case. (I haven't seen references to either the back injury or that Ryan attended the Naval Academy yet, maybe I missed those) If the answer is "It sells" Ok, offer that as an answer, it may be correct

Comment: Having seen the whole of S1 I can tell you that the **do** connect up the *basic mythos/background* of Jack Ryan Sr. just updated to the post 9/11 era rather than the Cold War which the original novels are based on.

Comment: @CosCallis At first I liked this question, and thought it just needed some tweaking. Then I read your comments. It's clear that you haven't seen enough of the show to make any statements about it as a whole. Please continue watching and come back when you're finished.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you, I will look forward to seeing how they do that.

Comment: @LevenTrek based on your answer and Paulie's comment I will probably come back around to accept your answer. (I appreciate that you managed to offer a cogent answer without a bunch of spoilers) After the first episode, and having read the books as they came off the press I was left _feeling_ "this isn't the Jack Ryan I know." ... thus the question.

Comment: I would argue that the movie "The Sum of All Fears" is barely recognizable to the book version. This is mostly a rant.

Answer (score 19):

Probably the most important element of Jack Ryan's personality is that **he's just an analyst** in the CIA, yet he repeatedly gets drawn into dangerous situations where he's forced to act as an operative. He succeeds, and even excels, despite his lack of operational training.

Arguably the second most important element of Jack Ryan is **his back injury**. While he was a Marine, he was in a serious helicopter crash that severely damaged his spine. It *could* have left him paralyzed, but he spent years learning to walk again, driven by his love of country and strength of character.

You mentioned **his boss, Jim Greer**. But he's more than just a black guy that Jack works with. Greer is a calculated and experienced intelligence officer, and sees Jack as young and brash - until he discover's Jack's value and becomes his mentor.

There's also **Cathy, his girlfriend, fiance, or wife** (depending on his age). Cathy is naturally loving and gentle, but like Jack, she has the capacity for complex tactics and great bravery when it's called for.

---

To be fair, there are differences between this Jack Ryan and other Jack Ryans. To make him more relatable to modern audiences, they replaced his cold war enemies with a Middle-Eastern terrorist.

**When the same character appears in different movies over such a long time period, these kinds of discrepancies are unavoidable.** The best comparison I can think of is James Bond, who has plenty of his own discrepancies over his decades of movies.

The Jason Bourne movies were able to maintain continuity, but only because the movies were so close together. Still, he's dramatically different from the Jason Bourne that appears in the original Robert Ludlum books.

Comment: Well done.  Don't forget that Cathy has always been a medical doctor but is now an epidemiologist, rather than the ophthalmologist she had been prior.

Comment: So I'm trying to find a name for this.  When you have a named hero, that hero can become an archtype, and you can tell inconsistent stories about the hero without causing distress in (at least some of) the audience, so long as the hero remains the hero.  Like camp fire stories about paul bunyian or whatever.

Comment: @Yakk I know what you mean. My dad used to tell me "Jack stories", which were basically parables about this random "any guy" who happened to be named Jack. How about... archehero? multi-character? legendary?

Comment: @LevenTrek It is more than that; that seems too narrow.  I mean, Jesus from the bible qualifies (the testaments aren't consistent).  Comic book heros (even within a given "reboot" their stories make more sense as disconnected, if locally reasonably sound).  Coyote stories.  Basically, the opposite of having a single canon narrative.